# Webpack Compilation Error con Cypress

Tags: vue.js, webpack, test

Estoy tratando de hacer pruebas unitarias con Cypress pero a la hora de importar un archivo vue al spec me sale el siguiente error:

> Error: Webpack Compilation Error ./src/components/Login.vue 1:0 Module
> parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate
> loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured
> to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Tengo instalado vue-loader y vue-template-compiler. Y en la configuación de webpack tengo declarado el vue-loader.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '@cypress/vue': path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ],
}
```

**cypress.json**

```
{
  "env": {
    "API_URL": "https://****"
  },
  "numTestsKeptInMemory": 10,
  "experimentalComponentTesting": true,
  "componentFolder": "src"
}
```

**cypress/plugins/index.js**

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
const preprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index')
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  preprocessor(on, config)
  return config
}
```

Comment: ¿Lo lograste solucionar?

Comment: La verdad es que no lo recuerdo, lo voy a intentar buscar, pero creo que ya no lo tengo